# What is a worker in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coming from the Java world and keep hearing this term 'worker' in the ruby/rails world.  What is it? a thread?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depends on the context.

A worker is typically a process that runs outside of your application request cycle. Ruby libraries like [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) are typically used to manage worker queues.

On the other hand, if we're talking about web servers the word "worker" is sometimes used interchangeably with threads or processes (ie: nginx or apache "workers").

Comment: @Kamilski81 in web servers and using the solutions outlined here, these would be separate processes. With delayed_job for instance, you can run many different worker processes that can all pop off the next highest priority task from the database.  Due to this architecture many people run an additional monitor process using something like God, or BluePill.  See here for more: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/server_monitoring

Answer (score 8):

Often in the 'Rails world' a worker is referring to a priority queue type system that has separate processes popping off tasks to execute outside the application cycle.  One of the most popular of these systems is [DelayedJobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). This uses a database migration to add a table to hold the tasks that are to be executed by a worker process.  You can then configure any number of worker processes that will check the DelayedJobs queue table and execute the serialized task.  With DelayedJobs you have not only the ability to set priority of different tasks, but also a timeframe to execute the task, eg. send a particular email 1 hour from now.

Answer (score 4):

A server running your rails app uses workers to do all of the things an application needs.  It sends email, runs requests, performs calculations etc.  The number of workers you need depends on how much traffic and calculations your web app needs to do.