# Ruby on Rails: connect a function with the bootstrap botton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [this example for file uploader.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)

Now it works this way:
I upload a file, after the file is saved,the function(do_picture_analyse) calls R and produces a histogram(simplest version, in the more complicated version 2 packages have to be installed in R), picture of the histogram is saved. The problem is that if I want to upload 50 files, it takes lots of time to load 2 packages in R for each file separately(after_save callback).

What I need:
I upload a file, file is saved, I click on a button "Histogram" and the function do_picture analyses is called on all files that are in the database( It doesnt matter if some of the files have already been analyzed)

So I need only to know how **to make an interaction between a button and a call of the function** and nothing more.

My show.html.erb:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">

       <td></td>
      <td class="name">
       <a href="{%=file.url%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
      </td>
       <td class="nam">
       <a href="{%=file.url_chip_image%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
      </td>


      <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>     

      <td class="Pic">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-info">Pic</button>    
      </td>

      <td class="Hist">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" >Hist</button>        
      </td>

      <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"> 
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>

        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

my upload.rb:

```
def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => (read_attribute(:upload_file_name)).split(".").first,
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE",
      "url_chip_image"=>read_attribute(:chip_image),

    }
  end


  after_save :do_picture_analyse


def do_picture_analyse
  if read_attribute(:chip_image)==nil

   require 'rinruby'
    myr = RinRuby.new(echo=false)

myr.filepath=upload.path(:original)
myr.fileurl=upload.url(:original)


myr.eval <<EOF
   s=read.table(filepath)
   for(j in nchar(filepath):1){
         if(substr(filepath,j,j)=="/"){      
           savepath<-substr(filepath,1,j-1)
           file.name<-filepath
           file.name<-substr(file.name,j+1,nchar(filepath)-4)

           break
         }
       }


  file.name1<-paste(file.name,"image.jpeg",sep="_")
  savepath<-paste(savepath,file.name1,sep="/")

   jpeg(filename=savepath,width=250, height=250)
   hist(s$V1) 
   dev.off()




EOF



  self.update_attributes(
    :chip_image => (((myr.fileurl).split("?").first)[6..-5]+'_image.jpeg')
  )
end

end
```

**EDIT:**

do_picture_analyse can take a folder as a parameter and analyse all files inside it by loading the the packages only one time for entire folder.There are only two folders for the files(two different types of files, let say .txt and .blabla files will be saved either in the txt-Folder or in a blabla-Folder. The type of the folder is saved in the database as well. By clicking the button, two folders should be passed to the do_picture_analyse and it will do everything
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new route for this :

```
resources :name_of_your_controller do
  # use this if you want a route like resources/:id/analyze (single file)
  get :analyze, on: :member 
  # use this if you want a route like resources/analyze (multiple files)      
  get :analyze, on: :collection
end
```

then create a new action on your controller :

```
def analyze
  # for single file analysis do something like this :
  @file = File.find( params[:id] )
  @file.do_picture_analyse
  respond_to do |format|
    # render what you need to render, js or html
  end

  # ... or do something like this for multiple file analysis :
  @files = File.where( params[:search] )
  @files.each {|f| f.do_picture_analyse )
  # etc.
end
```

you can then link your button to your action :

```
# single file
<%= link_to "Histogram", analyze_file_path( file ) %>
# multiple files
<%= link_to "Histogram", analyze_files_path( search: your_search_conditions ) %>
```

PS: if your method needs a lot of processing power (if you use R, i assume that you have complex calculations involved), you should consider to extract it [in a Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338029/what-is-a-worker-in-ruby-rails) to run it as a background task.

**edit**

response to your comments :

i think you should extract this method and make it a class method, that accepts one or more paths. 
Then create a collection route that points to your controller ; in your controller action load the files according to some params and does something like this :

```
# find the directories to be processed : 
paths = @files.map(&:folder_type).uniq
# pass them to your class method : 
File.do_picture_analyse(paths)
```

It is even possible to create a class methods that automatically handles these two steps for all files in a relation :

```
def self.perform_analysis!
  paths = all.map(&:folder_type).uniq # or uniq.pluck(:folder_type) on rails >= 3.2.1
  do_picture_analyse(paths)
end

def self.do_picture_analyse( *paths )
  # call R from here
end
```

then you can do :

```
File.where( your_search_params ).perform_analysis!
```

Comment: @files.each {|f| f.do_picture_analyse ) this means that it will still load packages for each file separately. do_picture_analyse can take a folder as a parameter and analyse all files inside it by loading the the packages only one time for entire folder.There are only two folders for the files(two different types of files, let say .txt and .blabla files will be saved either in the txt-Folder or in a blabla-Folder. The type of the folder is saved in the database as well. By clicking the button, two folders should be passed to the do_picture_analyse and it will do everything.

Comment: ps: using this approach, it is even possible to collect the exact files concerned and only process them, not the entire folders

Comment: I am sorry, i am quite new to Ruby on Rails. def self.perform_analysis!and self.do_picture_analyse mathods should be in controller, shouldn't it? And where should be File.where(....)?

Comment: no, these are class methods for the model. The File.where part can be in the controller. You should read a bit about ruby, the difference between class and instance methods is very important ; here's a short explanation of it : http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: What is self....analyse(*paths) ? Is it a pointer to paths? Cannot I use just self...analyse(path) ?

Comment: the * is called the splat operator. When using it in a method definition, you just signify that all arguments passed to the method will be stuffed into an array. Here's a post explaining it in details : http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/

Answer (score 1):

The short and sweet answer: in your `show.html.erb` write:

```
  <td class="Hist">
    <%= link_to 'Histogram', histogram_path, ;method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary" %>
  </td>
```

In your `config/routes.rb` add the following line

```
post '/histogram' => 'your-controller#histogram', :as => 'histogram'
```

THis means that the `histogram_path` will point to a controller named `your-controller` and call the action `histogram`. *Please* replace those with *your* names.

And then you should be good to go.

I have taken the liberty to propose a POST action, because I am assuming the action is not idempotent. If it is, you should use a GET.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems it doesnt work properly with show.html.erb, I do not see a button there, only a link /histogram that leads to /uploads/view?class=btn+btn-mini+btn-primary&amp;method=post.
And when I view a page in the html-code, it shows me following: <a href="/uploads/view?class=btn+btn-mini+btn-primary&amp;method=post">/histogram</a>

Comment: ow, classic. The [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper can handle two hashes: `url_options` and `html_options`, and I switched the order, and you need to make sure the html-options are in the second hash. I edited my answer, I hope this is correct now. This code is of course not tested :)

Comment: it still doesnt work somehow=). with :class=>"btn.." it tells me there is a SyntaxError in Uploads#show, unexpected ')', unepxted keyword_ensure,expecting ')', unexpected keyword_end. When I use it without :class everything is ok but it does nothing, it changes the only the internet address to localhost:3000/uploads/view?method=post and in the termonal it shows me: Started GET "/uploads/view?method=post"Processing by UploadController#show as HTML Parameters:{"method"=>"post","id"=>"view"}.   It seems it does not call #histogram at all. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: it works perfectly now. I have the inly and the last question: How to I redirect back to the page, where "Histogram"-Button stands? I tried smt like this post '/uploads/view' => 'your-controller#histogram', :as => 'histogram' but it does not work

Comment: From to controller? Just do write `redirect_to` instead of `render`. More info: see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html). Hope this helps. Man you make me work for my points, normally people ask 1 question in a question.