# how to check if a file is finished decompressing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a website where i upload a zip file and then the serverside decompresses it.   i've since moved to amazons S3 service which does not allow such things as decompressing.

I'm wondering, is there a way to check or monitor the status of that zip file- and then run my  model/method for pushing to s3?  i'd like to run it immediately after it's decompressed- otherwise i'd try a cronjob or something.

The only conclusion i can think of right now is to output the files unzipped in my view. then selecting those files and submitting again to the method for uploading.   but this seems cumbersome.

any thoughts on this?

Comment: have you considered using a worker ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338029/what-is-a-worker-in-ruby-rails

Comment: I'm sure you should use a worker to do these tasks in background, because compressing/decompressing can take a long time and forcing user to wait for these processes to end isn't a good idea.

Comment: the file sizes are extremely small.  that being said, even if i used a worker file- how would the worker know the decompression is completed?